# Высвобождение памяти delete[]

Tags: c++

Будет ли корректно работать код?

```
void *ptr_1;  
long *ptr_2;  
*ptr_2=new long[10];  
(long*)ptr_1=ptr_2;  
delete[] ptr_2;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, в том виде что вы привели, этот код даже компилироваться не будет, вот так он должен выглядеть:

```
void *ptr_1;  
long *ptr_2;  
ptr_2 = new long[10];  
ptr_1 = ptr_2;  
delete[] ptr_2;
```

Во-вторых, после того как выполнится `delete[] ptr_2;`, указатель `ptr_1` будет указывать на высвобожденную память, соответственно, любая попытка записи/чтения в/из нее приведет к ошибке.

Comment: А чтобы записать данные!? - (*(long*)ptr_2)[0]=123;

Comment: Да преобразования указателя (void *) там не нужно,а чтобы записать данные: `ptr_2[5] = 123;`

Comment: Приведение типа левой части оператора присваивания

(т.е. что-то вроде (void *)ptr_2 = ptr_1) компилятором вообще не приветствуется (warning deprecated).

Приводить надо либо тип правой части, либо тип указателя левой части (перед разыменованием указателя), т.е. задавая тип памяти, адресуемой указателем.

Comment: А откуда взялся `(void *)ptr_2 = ptr_1)`? Вы всё же аккуратней кнопки-то нажимайте, а то понять совсем трудно.